# How to get string by removing middle part in postgres

Tags: regex, postgresql

I want to remove middle string which is date and get the value in postgres

**Example**
**From this**

> `ABC_XYZ_20200129041836.csv` or `2ABC_XYZ_20200129041836.txt`

**to this**

> `ABC_XYZ.csv` or `2ABC_XYZ.txt`

I tried this regex `[^_]+$`. which selects all strings after last occurence of `_` including after `.` (e.g., `_20200129041836.csv`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use `REGEXP_REPLACE` here:

```
SELECT
    filename,
    REGEXP_REPLACE(filename, '^([^_]+_[^_]+)_.*(\..*)$', '\1\2') AS filenameshort
FROM yourTable;
```

The strategy here is to match and capture the first two portions of the filename occurring in between the `_` separators in one capture group, along with the extension in a second capture group.  Then, we replace with just that first and second capture group.

Comment: Thanks! This is what I want. BTW what is `\1\2`, I think concat matching group right ?

Comment: Yes it is concatenating the two capture groups.  Note that typically to concatenate two strings `||` is required though.

Comment: Hey! what if I have this string `ABC_XYZ_ABC_XYZ_20200129041836123.csv`.

Comment: ...and, what output would you expect in that case?

Comment: Output should be `ABC_XYZ_ABC_XYZ.csv`

Comment: Use: `REGEXP_REPLACE(filename, '^(.*)_.*(\..*)$', '\1\2')`

Comment: Cool that works, It would be helpful if you can explain this regex `^(.*)_.*(\..*)$` :)

Comment: The first `(.*)` greedily matches and captures everything up until the _last_ underscore.  The extension is captured using the same logic in my original answer.  You should avoid changing your question after others have already answered.

Answer (score 1):

Single occurrence is easy to handle with regexp_replace like:

```
select regexp_replace('ABC_XYZ_20200129041836.csv', '(.*)_[0-9]{14}([_.].*)', '\1\2');
```

Comment: Your answer works for me but what if I have `ABC_XYZ_ABC_XYZ_20200129041836123.csv` - any number not limited to 14

Comment: @SameerKhan You can simply change the {14} part to a range. Maybe {14, 17} if it could have milliseconds. This answer in fact aims to help when you have filenames like 'ABC_XYZ_20200129041836_v2.csv', from the question subject, I didn't see an assumption that the time part is always right before the file extension.

Comment: In case you need more precise detection of dates, this article may help: https://www.regular-expressions.info/dates.html